# Multischema view for postgres , querying multiple databases

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, dblink

Im managing SaaS app where each customer has a separate database (Postgres 9.3) . I need to figure out the best way to aggregate and query this data ( READ-only ). I know postgres has problems with quering multiple databases, *dblink* and *postgres_fdw* might be an option though. Has anyone got other solution to this problem ?

So far I've managed to come up with :

```
DataBase A \           / Schema A \
             DataBase C             View
DataBase B /           \ Schema B /
```

I could pg_dump Database A/B on regular intervals then recreate them in Database C as Schema A/B . In Database C I would create a View which I hopefully be able to query (Django ORM).

As this is rather tidious I would welcome any input!

1. I don't need DataBase C to be in absolute sync with Database A/B , it can lag few hours behind.
2. Since DataBase A/B are built from the same template I don't know what is going to happen with Indexes in final View ?
3. Django ORM has no support for schemas (yet) , so Im guessing I would need a View.

Comment: This is a re-post of http://stackoverflow.com/q/25415829/398670 . Please flag a question for migration instead of copying & pasting, or at least link between the copies.